# Creating a table in PHP for MySQL server (MySQLi)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

connection:

```
<?php 
$db_name = "xxx";
$mysql_username = "xxx";
$mysql_password = "xxx";
$server_name = "xxx";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

full code (this is the code for the registration) [edit] (am i getting closer?):

```
    <?php 
    require "conn.php";
    echo "debug 1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$username);
    $username = $_POST["username"]; 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    echo "debug 2";
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 0){ // username not taken
      echo "debug 3";
      $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO UserData (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
      $password =($_POST["password"]);
      $username =($_POST["username"]);  
      $stmt2->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
      $stmt2->execute();
       $MyServer = ($_POST["username"]);
  $stmt3 = $conn->prepare('CREATE TABLE ? (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
        )');
  $stmt3->bind_param('s',$username);
  $username = $_POST["username"];
  $stmt->execute();  
    ///mysqli_query(connection object,query)
      if ($stmt2->affected_rows == 1){
        echo 'Insert was successful.';

      }else{ echo 'Insert failed.';
       var_dump($stmt2);
      }
    }else{ echo 'That username exists already.';}
    ?>
```

I used this code to create a table with the name of the posted username. What is wrong with this for it is not working.

Comment: So far, you've got a string that contains an SQL statement. What are you doing with it? We need the code that you are using to run the query and the error you get.

Comment: put the code that you're using for executing the query you mentioned

Comment: how do I execute the query in MySQLi? (I am a beginner so please be specific)

Answer (score 0):

```
$MyServer = ($_POST["username"]);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE '$MyServer' (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    )";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

> mysqli_query(connection object,query)

you can execute your query as above.

Answer (score 0):

Just my personal preference.

```
$myServer = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["username"]);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE '$MyServer' (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    )";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

PDO is also an alternative.

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = '<INSERT DATABASE NAME HERE>';
$user = '<INSERT USERNAME HERE>';
$pass = '<INSERT PASSWORD HERE>';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('CREATE TABLE ? (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
        )');
$stmt->execute([$myServer]);
$success = $stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

use below line as ur sql vaiable

```
$sql = " create table if not exists  {$MyServer} (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    )";
```

and in mysql in table name single quotes(') are not there  it's `;